# Url.Action with specific port or relative

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with URL generation in my ASP.NET MVC project.

This code:

```
@Url.Action("Register", "Home", null, "https") }))
```

Generates absolute URL, which is generally fine, except that in my environment I have a load balancer before web servers, which are running ssl on different port than 443. I suspect, that application recognizes different port and generates URLs with port specified, ex:

```
https://www.example.com:449/Home/Register
```

The same happens with

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

etc.

How can I make the application always use the default port in generated urls?

```
https://www.example.com/Home/Register
```

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a couple of tests now, and I'm unable to reproduce this issue on MVC4. I'm running a HTTP server on a non-standard port and Url.Action() returns the absolute URL without a port number.

But if you're really struggling with this you can the [hostName parameter on `Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460297%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
@Url.Action("Register", "Home", null, "https", "example.com") // or you could use Request.Url.Host possibly?
```

Comment: I added a sample project on https://github.com/mdymel/urltesting
It seems, Url.Action generates absolute URL when you provide a controller name

Comment: @MichalDymel http://i.imgur.com/Mcj7kHa.png - I'm not seeing the issue here. Are you running this on IIS7?